# RTSP or HTTP protocol for progressive download

Tags: network-programming, protocols, progressive-download

Is RTSP or HTTP protocol more preferable to use for performing progressive download on server side and why ??

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1):

HTTP unless you need something like server side trick play that you can only easily get through RTSP because some carriers block RTSP.

Answer (score 0):

[RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) is designed specifically for streaming. HTTP is not. So chances are RTSP is better at streaming, depending on whether or not your server and client(s) implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is the streaming protocol from the VoIP world, and it runs over RTP/UDP. When using it, the client can stop, pause the video stream, and the bandwidth is used when it is needed.

Progressive download on other hand is a technique implemented over HTTP/TCP. It just gives an experience of streaming, but actually it is not. It just downloads the video file as if another HTTP download. Youtube is very good example.

It does not provide the pause, stop capability, and once the download is started it can be stopped only by closing the browser session. Even if the playback is stopped on the player, the download still happens in the background.

This makes the progressive download bandwidth inefficient, and when the browser session is closed (e.g. video is not interested), whatever video is downloaded, the bandwidth is wasted.